# Select specific columns in Logic apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to do something like SELECT column1, column2 in the Logic apps dataverse connector? I have a lot of data and I do not need all of it, I just need specific columns. I know you can do something like column1 eq 'something' but I'm not looking for a specific value.

I haven't been able to find anything in the docs about this. Is this another basic feature available MS "forgot" about? Due to how horribly slow and expensive Logic Apps can get when processing lots of data pulling all of it is not really an option.

Comment: Have you tried using `Get a row by ID` action with Select columns parameter? You can check more on it from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commondataserviceforapps/#get-a-row-by-id

Comment: Thanks for the link. I cannot use get row by ID but the docs did put me into the right direction. The $select option isn't exposed in the GUI but you can add it manually in code view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that come across this: You can filter on columns however this option is not exposed in the GUI for whatever reason.

The easiest way is to add the "filter" option in the GUI, then go into code view and look for your list action. You should see "$filter" in the query. Now replace "$filter" with "$select", save and go back into the normal view. You can now add the columns you want as a comma separated list (column1,column2) as per the link to the documentation that @SwethaKandikonda-MT posted.